# php form updating mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to update a mysql database with new information from an edit form I created. I cant put my finger on whats wrong. The code is popping a mysql error. Any ideas?

```
<?php
// connect to datebase
require "episodelist.db.php";
// real escape all strings
$season_num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['season_num']);
$eps_num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eps_num']);
$temp_eps_num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['temp_eps_num']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$inspired = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inspired']);
$descrip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descrip']);

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE $season SET season_num='$season_num', eps_num='$eps_num', temp_eps_num='$temp_eps_num', title='$title', inspired='$inspired', descrip='$descrip' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<a href='../episodelist_superadmin.html'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "Whoops: " . mysql_error(); ;
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''season' SET season_num='2', eps_num='test', temp_eps_num='3', title='(Unknown)'' at line 1

Comment: Variable `$season` was not defined. It should contain your table name.

Comment: It's interesting that there's a single-quote after the table name in the error message, but not in the code.  Does the variable contain a single quote that isn't being sanitized?

Comment: I removed the $ from in-front of season and it went thought...

Comment: Its all working now. Thanks for the 2nd set of eyes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the $ from in-front of season and it went thought and now its all working. Thanks for the 2nd set of eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be defining `$season` anywhere. As a result it's causing problems with your query syntax.

Personally I would avoid putting variables directly in strings and instead concatenate them (`"string".$var."more string"`).